# office 365 integration with B2C (not B2B)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to integrate my app using B2c to office 365. I have read that we can add a specific AAD to B2C or use B2B but I am looking for a direction in which user can select office 365 login button and using which they can use their office 365 account to login into my app.

I am able to integrate app to one specific AAD but i want a blanket office 365 integration with my B2C

What is envision is something like below. It will be good to have some direction on this.

[image]

Comment: 1. May I know what's your question? 2. Actually, the office 365 accounts is AAD accounts.

Comment: Sorry, Yang. To simplify, I just wanted to know how to set up sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory in B2C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom) describes how to enable sign-in for users using the multi-tenant endpoint for Azure AD by using custom policies in Azure AD B2C. This allows users to sign in from their Azure AD tenants to your Azure AD B2C tenant without you configuring a technical provider for each of their Azure AD tenants.

Comment: Thank you chris. Thanks a lot.. i have gone through this article before but missed this commented lines.. Thanks for pointing me to this. <!-- The commented key below specifies that users from any tenant can sign-in. Uncomment if you would like anyone with an Azure AD account to be able to sign in. -->
        <!-- <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/</Item> -->

Comment: I did implement multi-tenant endpoint for Azure AD but i ran into another issue. It is expecting user to be there on tenant AD. which it will because we are linking AppId from AD..  `code`  <!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID -->
        <Item Key="client_id">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Item>.. Am i missing something

Comment: Hi @prvnsaini: What do you mean "It is expecting user to be there on tenant AD"? What is the exact issue?

Comment: Sorry.. missed marking the application as multi-tenant. I have figured that out and its all good. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 supports OAuth2 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-office-365-exchange-online/

We can always configure an oauth2 provider in AzureAD B2C https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/oauth2-technical-profile

We'll require a multi tenant app which seeks minimum scope which don't require admin consent.